# Asp.net webparts or portlet like functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to let other parties use your website as their own content using their own style ?

We have build a small website for a customer, asp.net, .net framework 3.0. Now the customer wants other parties to be aple to use our website in their own websites while maintaining the styling of the costumers website.

I have done nothing like this before and don't even know what to google, so any help is appriciated.

- I know you can do this with sharepoint, but to use sharepoint for such a small site seems like a lot of overkill
- it sounds that portlets is a good name for what they want. but googling portlets draws me in the world of java and doesn't give me a lot of info on what the other parties would have to do to make it work.
- a simple Iframe would probably take me a long way, but how can you get the styling done within an Iframe
- webparts also sound interesting , but they seem more for in project sharing then letting people use them in their own site.

It is a small website and the logic and backend communication is pretty good contained, so a complete rework of the frond-end is not a big problem.

Once again, any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Omar Al Zabir has a book on how to build a Portal in ASP.NET- here is a link to [his Website](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/Default.aspx).

You might want to look at his [Dropthings portal](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/Default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info, look s like an interesting book. My first impression is that it focuses more on a in-house portal and all the functionality that a portal has.

Comment: I've not read it myself. In Java the Portlet standard used to be JSR-168 (I know there were working on a newer version). You can actually write Java Portlets in C#- a company called Mainsoft does a converter. I don't recommend that route though. You might also want to look into dotnetnuke.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, portlets are pretty much Java-only, despite any talk of standards.

If you can encapsulate your pages in web parts or user controls, that would make it easy to style them, and even to parameterize them: a web part can be configured.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that to deploy the webparts, we need to put them in a dll, deploy this to the potential customers and let them use it in aspx pages ?

Comment: I don't know, actually. I've worked with custom (server) controls before as a deployable unit, but never with web parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kalitte Dynamic Dashboards for creating professional dashboards and portlets.

More information can be found at [www.dynamicdashboards.net](http://www.dynamicdashboards.net)